# How to disable Gutenberg editor?

Tags: plugins, filters, visual-editor, block-editor

As the 5.0 is getting real, and so is Gutenberg...

Is it possible to disable Gutenberg and use previous TinyMCE editor?

How to do this?

Comment: No need to make things bulky by custom code change. When you use Gutenberg, you also get a toggle feature(backward compatibility). On hover of each post, you would see the link “Classic editor” which lets you go back to classic editor. - Achin

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/ This plugin allows you to disable it entirely, or you have an option to use either the classic editor or the new editor on a per post basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can disable it.

### You can do this with code

If you want to disable it globally, you can use this code:

```
if ( version_compare($GLOBALS['wp_version'], '5.0-beta', '>') ) {
    // WP > 5 beta
    add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post_type', '__return_false', 100 );
} else {
    // WP < 5 beta
    add_filter( 'gutenberg_can_edit_post_type', '__return_false' );
}
```

And if you want to disable it only for given post type, you can use:

```
function my_disable_gutenberg_for_post_type( $is_enabled, $post_type ) {
    if ( 'page' == $post_type ) {  // disable for pages, change 'page' to you CPT slug
        return false;
    }

    return $is_enabled;
}
if ( version_compare($GLOBALS['wp_version'], '5.0-beta', '>') ) {
    // WP > 5 beta
    add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post_type', 'my_disable_gutenberg_for_post_type', 10, 2 );
} else {
    // WP < 5 beta
    add_filter( 'gutenberg_can_edit_post_type', 'my_disable_gutenberg_for_post_type', 10, 2 );
}
```

PS. If you don't want to support older versions, you can ignore filters beginning with 'gutenberg_', so no version checking is needed in such case.

### Or using one of existing plugins

1. [Classic Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/)
2. [Disable Gutenberg](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/)
3. [Guten Free Options](https://wordpress.org/plugins/guten-free-options/)
4. [Gutenberg Ramp](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg-ramp/)

Comment: Should be an option in the settings when WordPress 5 is launched. To choose between classic and block (Gutenberg) editor.

Comment: @AndréKelling totally agree

Comment: @AndréKelling -- Looks like there isn't one. We're being told what to use.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the answer is no. Gutenberg stores content in a different format than how the pre 5.0 editor did. YMMV significantly if you try to disable gutenberg after content was already created, things might work for core blocks, but blocks created by plugins, who knows.

Now if the question is about disabling before having any content edited in gutenberg, then you have a better chance with the other answers, but this is going to be a short term bandaid fix and is not a long term proper strategy. 
In the long term all those options are not going to be tested against or just bit rot. And on top of that you might have a limited selection of themes and plugins you can work with.

5.0 have already hard coded gutenberging of sample content. you are not going to escape the need to use it by hacks.

If you want to use WordPress you should embrace its core features, and you do not want to build technical debt and be forced to migrate to gutenberg on a rush. It is better to just do it once it stabilizes and get done with it.

If you do not want to embrace WordPress core features, why do you use it?

Comment: It’s not exactly true with the different format. Content is still stored in post_content, and is saved as HTML. Of course you won’t be able to edit that content the same way (unless you used dynamic blocks), but it will be possible. Gutenberg stores it’s metadata as comments, so it won’t break anything.

Comment: of course it is different, in "old" html comments are not significant and with "new" they are, and this is just the most obvious difference.Next in line would be that "old" uses new line as paragraph boundary while "new" directly inserts <p> elements. The fact both formats use the same DB field is the least significaant

Comment: In new they are also not significant for rendering posts (unless you use dynamic blocks). Static blocks will display correctly and you’ll be able to edit them as HTML. It’s not a different format - it just adds more meta comments. It’s also not true that comments are insignificant in old editor (you already use some meta comments as more or nextpage) ;)

Comment: you should try it instead of speculating. try editing something with gutenberg, add an ACF block to the content. Now switch to classic editor and tell me what you see and if you can actually edit it (ok, I am guessing here about how ACF blocks works). Formats are not compatible, this is DB design 101, once the parsing is different you are not compatible any more.

Comment: Mark, I’m testing Gutenberg for over 6 months now ;) We’ve also organized a meetup with one of Gutenberg’s devs here in Wroclaw (in May, or even earlier). Please - read carefully - I clearly stated “unless you use dynamic blocks...

Comment: I do not get what is "dynamic block". How does a user supposed to know what is "dynamic block" to avoid using them if he desires content portability? User is encouraged to use things like the recent posts block, what should it do if he decided that GB is not for him? What should he do if he has a two years old paid plugin which assume that autop needs to be done on `post_content`?

Comment: your arguments are true also for shortcodes... If you remove a plugin that adds a shortcode, then that shortcode stops working. Are you trying to convince mi that registering a shortcode is causing entirely new format of storage? No, of course not. Dynamic block is official name for blocks which content is generated on server (https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/). Such blocks won't destroy the site - they just won't be rendered (even nicer solution than with shortcodes).

Comment: And yes - blocks can be registered by third-party plugins - so after removing one of those plugins, such blocks won't work too...

Comment: As I said, this is DB design 101. You might be able to hack around things or use them in a way which reduce the possibility for backward compatibility breakage, but sooner or later the breakage will happen and you will not be able to use different tools with the same DB. A great day to day example is how for many years different versions of word will display the same .doc file differently (or fail to load it). The fact it is still just one file that didn't change (and GB do change the content) do not help in the end

Answer (score 2):

I just added this in my function.php and it works great

```
add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Gutenberg by installing the Classic Editor plugin 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/
This will disable the Gutenberg Editor.

Thanks